# Key storage and Password Management Tool

Tags: key-management

Passwords are not stored in plain text. So we hash them. But for hashing we need a  key if we use a keyed hash function. In unix system passwords were stored in etc\password file but  now the location has changed. Where the keys for the hash functions are stored and does the password management tool handles the key storage?

Zulfi.

Comment: I don't think keyed hash functions are stored for storing passwords. AFAIK, generally, a random salt is generated for each password and the combination of password and salt is hashed and stored.

Comment: Okay where is the salt stored?

Comment: Along with the hash. I think in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is not the same thing as crypting. The latter is expected to be invertible (you want to extract the original message from the crypted one), while the former should not be: in an ideal world an ideal hashing algo could only be attacked by brute force. For that reason, a serious hash require a good deal of processing time to make brute force expensive enough for attackers not to even try to.

Because of that, hashes use no keys and nothing is hidden in the way to compute then: knowing the plain text (and the salt) you can easily compute the hash - simply it will take some time - and the salt is just stored along with the hash value.